# Preciso adicionar todos os anúncios ao string.xml?

Tags: android, admob, anúncio

Já sei que devo criar um bloco para cada actvity do meu aplicativo que eu queira que exiba anúncios, mas não sei como se dá a modificação do `string.xml` (se houver) após já ter sido adicionado o primeiro bloco de anúncios:

`string.xml` ([fonte do código](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-br))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
</resources>
```

Gostaria de saber se terei de adicionar os outros blocos de anúncio ao código do `string.xml`, mas sem necessariamente mudar o nome para diferenciar um do outro:

`string.xml` (retirado [daqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-br) e modificado por mim).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-1239402565465465/2363007813</string>
</resources>
```

Ou se por acaso terei de mudar o nome:

`string.xml` (retirado [daqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-br) e modificado por mim).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id_02">ca-app-pub-1239402565465465/2363007813</string>
</resources>
```

Links que podem ser úteis:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-br

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting?hl=pt-br#test_ads /

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 0):

Cada anúncio tem seu próprio id, logo o strings.xml tem que ter itens com nomes diferentes para representar cada id (até porque nem é possível ter 2 itens quaisquer no XML com o mesmo nome).

Por outro lado, você pode reusar o mesmo anúncio em vários locais do app. Não precisa, por exemplo, criar 2 banners com id's diferentes apenas para exibir em activities diferentes. Pode usar o mesmo banner.